# How to automatically copy text out of excel files

Tags: excel

I have 250 Microsoft Excel (.xls) files, all in a folder. I need to do the following:

```
for each file:
    open the file
    switch to a specific tab in the file
    extract the text from rows 15-100 on that tab
    save the text in a text file somewhere
```

I assume this can be automated somehow, but I have no idea how. Where do I start looking to figure out how to do this? I really don't want to open 250 excel files and copy text out by hand, as that would take hours. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have Excel, you can create an Excel macro in a separate worksheet to do this; just make sure the worksheet is outside of the directory you are parsing.  You'll need to add a reference for the FileSystemObject, which should be found in C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractData()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim oFolder As Folder

    Dim sFileOutput As String
    Dim fNum

    Dim excelFile As Excel.Workbook
    Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    sFileOutput = "C:\FolderToScan\ExcelOutput.txt"

    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\FolderToScan")

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If Right(oFile.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
            fNum = FreeFile()
            Open sFileOutput For Append As fNum

            Set excelFile = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)

            Set excelWorksheet = excelFile.Sheets(1)
            'Or:
            ' Set excelWorksheet = excelFile.Sheets("Name of your sheet")

            For i = 15 To 100
                Write #fNum, excelWorksheet.Cells(i, 1)
            Next
            Close #fNum

            excelFile.Close
            Set excelFile = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I gave you +1, but why do you think this is 'goofy'?

Comment: @Doc Brown - I just found it a little amusing to use Excel as a programming platform to iterate through other Excel worksheets.  It does detract from the answer, though, so I'm removing the comment.  Thank you for the edit as well!

Comment: Thanks! Just got this working, it worked great and it'll be incredibly useful in future.

Answer (score 1):

That can be quickly solved using the xlrd module and python, I copied the following example from activestate.com - it is easy to adapt it to your needs.

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483742/ (r3)
class readexcel(object):
""" Simple OS Independent Class for Extracting Data from Excel Files 
    the using xlrd module found at http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.htm

    Versions of Excel supported: 2004, 2002, XP, 2000, 97, 95, 5, 4, 3
    xlrd version tested: 0.5.2

    Data is extracted by creating a iterator object which can be used to 
    return data one row at a time. The default extraction method assumes 
    that the worksheet is in tabular format with the first nonblank row
    containing variable names and all subsequent rows containing values.
    This method returns a dictionary which uses the variables names as keys
    for each piece of data in the row.  Data can also be extracted with 
    each row represented by a list.

    Extracted data is represented fairly logically. By default dates are
    returned as strings in "yyyy/mm/dd" format or "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss",
    as appropriate.  However, dates can be return as a tuple containing
    (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Second) which is appropriate for usage
    with mxDateTime or DateTime.  Numbers are returned as either INT or 
    FLOAT, whichever is needed to support the data.  Text, booleans, and
    error codes are also returned as appropriate representations.

    Quick Example:
    xl = readexcel('testdata.xls')
    sheetnames = xl.worksheets()
    for sheet in sheetnames:
        print sheet
        for row in xl.getiter(sheet):
            # Do Something here
    """ 
def __init__(self, filename):
    """ Returns a readexcel object of the specified filename - this may
    take a little while because the file must be parsed into memory """
    import xlrd
    import os.path
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise NameError, "%s is not a valid filename" % filename
    self.__filename__ = filename
    self.__book__ = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    self.__sheets__ = {}
    self.__sheetnames__ = []
    for i in self.__book__.sheet_names():
        uniquevars = []
        firstrow = 0
        sheet = self.__book__.sheet_by_name(i)
        for row in range(sheet.nrows):
            types,values = sheet.row_types(row),sheet.row_values(row)
            nonblank = False
            for j in values:
                if j != '':
                    nonblank=True
                    break
            if nonblank:
                # Generate a listing of Unique Variable Names for Use as
                # Dictionary Keys In Extraction. Duplicate Names will
                # be replaced with "F#"
                variables = self.__formatrow__(types,values,False)
                unknown = 1
                while variables:
                    var = variables.pop(0)
                    if var in uniquevars or var == '':
                        var = 'F' + str(unknown)
                        unknown += 1
                    uniquevars.append(str(var))
                firstrow = row + 1
                break
        self.__sheetnames__.append(i)
        self.__sheets__.setdefault(i,{}).__setitem__('rows',sheet.nrows)
        self.__sheets__.setdefault(i,{}).__setitem__('cols',sheet.ncols)
        self.__sheets__.setdefault(i,{}).__setitem__('firstrow',firstrow)
        self.__sheets__.setdefault(i,{}).__setitem__('variables',uniquevars[:])
def getiter(self, sheetname, returnlist=False, returntupledate=False):
    """ Return an generator object which yields the lines of a worksheet;
    Default returns a dictionary, specifing returnlist=True causes lists
    to be returned.  Calling returntupledate=True causes dates to returned
    as tuples of (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Second) instead of as a
    string """
    if sheetname not in self.__sheets__.keys():
        raise NameError, "%s is not present in %s" % (sheetname,\
                                                      self.__filename__)
    if returnlist:
        return __iterlist__(self, sheetname, returntupledate)
    else:
        return __iterdict__(self, sheetname, returntupledate)
def worksheets(self):
    """ Returns a list of the Worksheets in the Excel File """
    return self.__sheetnames__
def nrows(self, worksheet):
    """ Return the number of rows in a worksheet """
    return self.__sheets__[worksheet]['rows']
def ncols(self, worksheet):
    """ Return the number of columns in a worksheet """
    return self.__sheets__[worksheet]['cols']
def variables(self,worksheet):
    """ Returns a list of Column Names in the file,
        assuming a tabular format of course. """
    return self.__sheets__[worksheet]['variables']
def __formatrow__(self, types, values, wanttupledate):
    """ Internal function used to clean up the incoming excel data """
    ##  Data Type Codes:
    ##  EMPTY 0
    ##  TEXT 1 a Unicode string 
    ##  NUMBER 2 float 
    ##  DATE 3 float 
    ##  BOOLEAN 4 int; 1 means TRUE, 0 means FALSE 
    ##  ERROR 5 
    import xlrd
    returnrow = []
    for i in range(len(types)):
        type,value = types[i],values[i]
        if type == 2:
            if value == int(value):
                value = int(value)
        elif type == 3:
            datetuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(value, self.__book__.datemode)
            if wanttupledate:
                value = datetuple
            else:
                # time only no date component
                if datetuple[0] == 0 and datetuple[1] == 0 and \
                   datetuple[2] == 0: 
                    value = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % datetuple[3:]
                # date only, no time
                elif datetuple[3] == 0 and datetuple[4] == 0 and \
                     datetuple[5] == 0:
                    value = "%04d/%02d/%02d" % datetuple[:3]
                else: # full date
                    value = "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % datetuple
        elif type == 5:
            value = xlrd.error_text_from_code[value]
        returnrow.append(value)
    return returnrow

def __iterlist__(excel, sheetname, tupledate):
    """ Function Used To Create the List Iterator """
    sheet = excel.__book__.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    for row in range(excel.__sheets__[sheetname]['rows']):
        types,values = sheet.row_types(row),sheet.row_values(row)
        yield excel.__formatrow__(types, values, tupledate)

def __iterdict__(excel, sheetname, tupledate):
    """ Function Used To Create the Dictionary Iterator """
    sheet = excel.__book__.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    for row in range(excel.__sheets__[sheetname]['firstrow'],\
                 excel.__sheets__[sheetname]['rows']):
        types,values = sheet.row_types(row),sheet.row_values(row)
        formattedrow = excel.__formatrow__(types, values, tupledate)
        # Pad a Short Row With Blanks if Needed
        for i in range(len(formattedrow),\
                       len(excel.__sheets__[sheetname]['variables'])):
            formattedrow.append('')
        yield dict(zip(excel.__sheets__[sheetname]['variables'],formattedrow))
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483742/ }}}
```