# Dealing with excel files what can be used besides VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on an excel file which will combine each of the excel files
sent by the users. So I will have a user entry row per file.

I started by using VBA. I thought that it would be the best, natural choice, though 
I did not know how to use it previously. At the moment I have come across problems that I have no idea how to solve in VBA - I want to open each of the excel files that contains a user form seamlessly even if it contains VBA code, but what happens is that each opening user gets a dialog that requires them to accept or reject VBA.

I really like to learn new things but it is starting to annoy me. I do hope there some other solution to do that, but not in VBA.  Is it possible to do that in some other language, and fire it from VBA?

I would love to have all bounded in that master excel file, or at most just to provide some library. The excel version is 2003.

Comment: Did you not read the answer I gave you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885733/excel-summary-of-many-excel-files-data-into-one-report-excel in your previuos post?

Answer (score 0):

how are you opening the file?  Workbooks.Open will open an excel file which has vba without asking the user to accept or reject code.

Perhaps its an issue with the security settings you have. You can check these out from the menu - Tools, Macro and then security

Answer (score 0):

your question is not well defined.

if you need to manipulate Excel files without opening Excel program, you can use other programming languages. Either interface with the COM / ActiveX objects that excel provides to the operating system, or use independent libraries (e.g. for PHP, Java, Python and more).

Another solution (to whatever problem you may have) is to use OpenOffice for working with excel files. It has its own macro language, as well as built-in bridges and interfaces to java & python.